# What is the easiest way to record a list of actions of the browser and replay them over and over?

Tags: javascript, macros

I want to be able to go a specific webpage like:http://something.com then goto: "javascript:playsong();" then click on a button and  after a specific amount of time do it again.

If you also know how to make a javascript code be run on a page with a firefox plugiin or something that would help too.

THankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is designed to do this, as is Windmill, FITnesse, WebDriver and Watin.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't include automatic recording, but I think you can do what you need with [Greasemonkey](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).  It allows you to write custom scripts that run every time you visit a particular page.  For the button, you can use the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) method, or just do whatever the button does in your own script.  For the time aspect, use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).